# Sudo User: Not able to see the home directory of other users

Tags: files, permissions, security, sudo

I created `sudo` user `hrsupport` with following commands:

```
hrsupport ALL=ALL, NOPASSWD: /bin/chown, /bin/chmod, /bin/chgrp, /scripts/pkgacct, /scripts/restorepkg
```

How can I achieve this

1. The `hrsupport` should be able to create & delete files on other directories like `/home/someone`
2. The `hrsupport` not able to `cd` to `home/someone/public_html`, which is having `nobody` as a group
3. The `hrsupport`user should be able to execute only the above commands + Other commands which are common for any users.

Comment: You have given unlimited access to `chmod`, `chown` and `chgrp`. The remaining conditions are pointless.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your proposed half-baked implementation is severely flawed.

Answer (score 0):

After long time, I am able to find the answer.

Problem: ==> The hrsupport not able to cd to home/someone/public_html, which is having nobody as a group

Solution: ==> I added the hrsupport user to the group nobody

Problem Solved.